# How to make plugin work in each template in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, templates, plugins

I am new to plugin development .I want to get all images of a particular page/post and want to show them as slideshow below the page ..Currently i am able to gather all images in media library and display it...But i want images if that particular page ..I have learnt that to get images of particular template u need to add lines of code in that specific post template ..But how that can be done using a plugin

```
$query_images_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
        $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
    }
foreach($images as $item){

   /// any function not yet decided
}
echo($item);
```

I m getting image urls in $item ..
I want to change the image attributes and replace the original image with my maniplulated image at the original position.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [portfolio slideshow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portfolio-slideshow/) ... for one (but this one gets high reviews and it's well-respected)

Comment: I want to change the image attributes and replace the original image with my maniplulated image at the original position..I want to happen it in my plugin and not using different plugin..